# WPF application not working in windows server 2003/2008

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows-server-2008

My wpf application is not working in windows server 2003/2008. when i click on icon i get the following error

```
Problem signature:
Problem Event Name: CLR20r3
Problem Signature 01:   networksolution.exe
Problem Signature 02:   1.0.0.0
Problem Signature 03:   50bc6790
 Problem Signature 04:  System.Data.SqlServerCe
Problem Signature 05:   3.5.1.0
Problem Signature 06:   4b743b2d
Problem Signature 07:   49e
Problem Signature 08:   1d
Problem Signature 09:   System.Windows.Markup.XamlParse
OS Version: 6.1.7600.2.0.0.272.7
Locale ID:  1033
Additional Information 1:   0a9e
Additional Information 2:   0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
Additional Information 3:   0a9e
Additional Information 4:   0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789

Read our privacy statement online:
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement     offline:
C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt
```

and it is not showing any window

what to do now?

Comment: It would help to see the code causing the crash. Unless you can provide us more information we can't really help.  Windows Server 2003 ( XP ) an Windows Server 2008 ( Vista ) have no problem running WPF applications.  So the problem must be with your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does your app use Microsoft SQL CE? If so I would recommend that you check that the server has the SQL CE engine installed.

From the error message you have shown it seems that it may be missing.

Comment: This line in the quoted error log: `Problem Signature 04:  System.Data.SqlServerCe`